# Google Apps async-fetch for 100 req/sec

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

I need to get nearly 100 pages in limited time and send results codes as response back.
Google Apps have a limit with 10 async req in one time. I'm thinking about queues but they work in background, maybe billable app can help?
Here is my code, when there more then 14 urls[] it fails with:

> File
>   "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py",
>   line 371, in _get_fetch_result
>       raise DeadlineExceededError(str(err)) DeadlineExceededError: ApplicationError: 5

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
   results = []
   urls = [ "http://google.com/",
            "http://yahoo.com",
            "http://goo.gl",
            "http://stackoverflow.com",
            "http://windows.com",
            "http://wikipedia.org"
            ]
   counter = len(urls)

   def handle_result(self, rpc, rowIndex):
      self.counter -= 1
      result = rpc.get_result()
      if result:
         self.results.append(str(rowIndex)+": "+str(result.status_code)+"<br>")
      if not self.counter:
         self.response.out.write("".join(self.results))

   def create_callback(self, rpc, rowIndex):
      return lambda: self.handle_result(rpc, rowIndex)

   def get(self):
      rpcs = []
      rowIndex = 0
      for url in self.urls:
         rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline = 10)
         rpc.callback = self.create_callback(rpc, rowIndex)
         urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, url)
         rpcs.append(rpc)
         rowIndex += 1
      # Finish all RPCs, and let callbacks process the results.
      for rpc in rpcs:
         rpc.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can may enqueue the task, then using the [channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html) notify and send the result to the user. Currently, channels only work with Javascript clients. Google plans to implement channels clients on other languages, or at least document the channel client for anyone who wants to write an implementation of them.

Comment: It will be great if Channels work with Google App Script which makes requests to my app.